# TinyMCE content handling on drag/drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

If you use your mouse to select many elements on a random web page, then you want to insert these content into the tinymce editor (by holding your mouse and drag the content into the editor), how do you catch the event "drop" and process the drop content before inserting into the editor?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: You can't. The dragdrop of html elements is like CtrlC CtrlV on windows. You can handle ondrop after content injection but not before

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
 setup: function(ed) {
   ...
   ed.on('init', function(event) {

     $(ed.getBody().parentNode).bind('drag drop', function(e) {
         /* your magic code here */
     });

   });
 }
```